# How to add one more column in the select using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use Laravel Eloquent to make a query. I would like to group the results by the `level` column, count the results in a `total` alias, and finally, bring me the `id` of each result. What am I doing wrong?

```
$fodas = Foda::groupBy('level')
             ->select('level', DB::raw('count (*) as total'))
             ->get();
```

The result is a collection that only brings me the level and total fields.

Comment: If you want the id from the result, you will need to select the `id`. If you are grouping sql side with strict mode on in mysql, your `group by` clause and `select` clause will need to reference identical columns.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see this pattern with many laravel facades. If you are handling 'one of something', in this case a column, you pass a string and if you are handling many of something, you pass an array.

That's why `*` and `level` are both valid. Because `*` is recognized a column and is expanded inside mysql to match every column.

And that's also why it doesn't work when you try to query for 'level, column2, column3' because this string is not a valid column name, so you have to pass an array with all the columns you want to use.

```
   $fodas = Foda::groupBy('level')
      ->select(['level','other','column'], DB::raw('count (*) as total'))
      ->get();
```

As I said before, this applies to many laravel facades:

```
Facade::function('one_thing');
//or
Facade::function(['thing1','thing2','thing3']);
//or even this, for some cases
Facade::function('thing1','thing2','thing3');
```

Comment: please make sure you add more details on what the answer is. Just adding code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You're both right. I was in a hurry and rushed the answers. Thank you for the input.